# JQuery and Javascript doesn't work in my project, but on web does

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

I reused a code that I saw on StackOverFlow with my data : http://jsfiddle.net/ctx3H/91/ , but when I'm importing him in Visual Studio 10 the buttons doesn't work.
I include in the head the following declaration:

```
<link href="../../../../Content/Areas.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/jquery-ui.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../../../Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Basically my page contains this declaration + from that site [Javascript code + HTML] What I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: Check the include path of jQuery: `../../../../Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.js`.

Comment: My guess is that your path to your jquery file is wrong. Check the developer console in whatever browser you're using to see any errors.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

reverse

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/jquery-ui.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../../../Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Always import jQuery package before dependant packages like jQueryUI

Comment: Good call, totally missed that.

Comment: A lesson to remeber . THANKS... BIG THANKS

Answer (score 0):

```
alert(jQuery);
```

will test if jQuery's been loaded successfully.